# Trying to understand the use of escape character '\t' with print function

Tags: python, string, printing, jupyter-lab

I was playing around with print() and its end = "\t" argument with strings and integers. When I use integers inside, I don't seem to see the 'tab' effect at output.

Say,

```
print("Hello","mn", end="\t")
print("World")
```

Output:

```
Hello mn    World
```

But the below,

```
print("123","567", end="\t")
print("no!")
```

Output:

```
123 567 no!
```

That could be something dumb on my part, but I'm not sure what it could be. Thanks!

I'm using a Python 3 Jupyter-lab kernel.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python and everything to do with the terminal itself. It also has nothing to do with whether you use strings or integers; it depends purely on the length of the output. (Also, your example of "using integers" is *not actually using integers*. A string that has digits in it is **not** an integer.)

Comment: I voted to close this question because the underlying problem is really a general "how do computers work" question rather than an actual *programming* question. The behaviour has a very long history, going back to typewriters, and is best answered by researching the concept of the `tab stop`, e.g. [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_stop).